# menu bar is not appearing in JMETER IDE

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, manual-testing, system-testing

[jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHd19.png)

when ever I try to save my test isn't saving and showing error.Even menu bar is not appearing in above image
**ERROR:** = java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.FileDialoger in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main].

Answer (score 0):

As per [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling#use) article it's recommended to use the latest version of JMeter and JDK if possible so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6) as you might be suffering from a bug which has already been fixed.

If you have to stay with JMeter 5.4.1 and the JDK you're using you can switch JMeter's look and feel as the issue seems to be connected with the dark theme.

Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.laf=CrossPlatform
```

or whatever [property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#laf_config) which is not "dark" and next time you run JMeter it will look better and the issue will go away.